# Unable to run methods on imported arrays and maps in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have made a map called `queue` in FILE 1 which is all built up in FILE 1 and then after it's all built up with all its values and keys I export it to FILE 2 by using `module.exports.queue = (queue)`.

FILE 1:

```
let queue = new.Map()
let key = "some keys"
let value = "some values"
if(!queue.has(key)){
        queue.set(key, new Set(value));

       } else{
         queue.get(key).add(value);

       }
module.exports.queue = (queue)
```

Now in FILE 2 I made a variable `Words = require("./FILE 1")` and after that I did `let x = Words.queue.keys()` and then logged `x` to the console which gave the error that it cannot read property 'keys' of undefined.

FILE 2:

```
let Words = require("./FILE1")
let x
x = Words.queue.keys()
console.log(x)
```

I then tried making an array in FILE 1 which will include `queue.keys` and then imported it to FILE 2 but then I was stuck with the problem that I could not check what the values are for a specific key anymore. (If you know a solution for this please let me know, I basically want to get the values for a specific key from the map and then put those values in an array for further functions).

Answer (score 0):

I am confused why this wont solve your problem.

```
let Words = require("./FILE1")
let value = Words.queue.get('your specific key')
console.log(value)
```

Comment: Thats what confusing me too cause technically it should work but it is giving an error 

value = Words.queue.get(guildIDString)
                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: could it be that you are having a file name issue.

Comment: no cause just console logging queue by doing console.log(Words.queue) in the second file  logs the whole queue so thats not the problem

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things going on here:

You instantiate new maps as follows:

```
const queue = new Map();
```

You have `new.map()`

Second, when you're calling your keys you're currently calling `Words.queue.keys()` which is wrong, it should be

```
words.keys();
```

Now what you're trying to build here is a queue and that's not necessarily the greatest approach think of reusability here. Declare it using a class in javascript inside of file 1, then import it to file2 and build your queue there the idea is that you can import your queue anywhere and build any queues you want whenever you need them.  Queues have plenty of methods enqueue(add to the queue) dequeue (remove from the queueu) so on... that go along with them and you can do an amazing read here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-queue-javascript/.

It's a bit difficult to understand at a quick glance here what you're trying to do and what you mean by getting the value of keys (are the keys an object-like structure or simply values inside of an array?) as queues aren't really made to search for values, you may require a linked list or some other structure...

If you can clarify or present your end result of what you're trying to achieve would go a long way for those of us here looking to help you out.

Comment: Ok so fist of all new.map() was a typing mistake it is actually new Map() in the actual code .

What I am trying to build here is a map (Here named queue, You can name it anything) which includes (If you are familiar with discord.js) the message.guild.id which is a number and I set that number as a key for example 77650317899228728918 is the key and then with a discord command I get the values for this key from the user and put them in a set so basically my map looks like this: ( Map(1) { '77650317899228728918' => Set(1) { 'a' } } ) here a is the value by the user and then

Comment: Continued:

and then I want to use this map in another javascript file which reads all the messages and gets the message.guild.id for the messages checks with the map if that guild id is there as a key and then checks what are the values of that key and if they are in the messages and then runs a command. So basically what I am stuck at is the second part that is importing the map to the second file and then checking for the message.guild.id and then values of that guild id in the map (PS: I used sets because one guild ID can have multiple values)

Comment: Well what do you think?